# Encoder difference between Spark DataFrame and Dataset

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When reading about the differences between Spark's `DataFrame` (which is an alias for `Dataset[Row]`) and `Dataset`, it's often mentioned that `Dataset`s make use of `Encoders` to efficiently convert to/from JVM objects to Spark's internal data representation. In scala, there are implicit encoders provided for case classes and primitive types. However, there is also the [`RowEncoder`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/encoders/RowEncoder.scala) which, I believe, achieves encoding for the `Row` in DataFrames.

My questions are

1. In terms of efficient conversion between JVM objects and Spark's internal binary representation, are `DataFrame`s and `Dataset`s the same in performance?
2. What additional benefits do a specific type (like a case class in Scala) provide over the generic `Row` as far as Encoding (serializing/deserializing) goes? Apart from compile-time type-safety, do typed JVM objects provide any advantage over semi-typed (or "untyped") `Row`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dataframes are just datasets with an encoder for the Spark Row class. So in essence a Dataframe is a Dataset.

Encoders also do not come into play at all unless you are using non column functions (functions that take a lambda like map, reduce, flatmap.) The moment that you do use one of those functions there will be a performance hit as you break the codegen that catalyst is doing into two parts since it can't optimize the lambda. This means your probably don't want to be using those functions at all and can ignore the dataset/Dataframe difference entirely since if you don't use those functions you won't ever encode.

In my experience the benefit of the type safety you can get with a Dataset and the types apis is not worth the huge perf hit. In almost all cases I've found that you should stay in Dataframes and only use column based functions and udfs for best performance.

As an additional note, the only other time an encoder will be used is when you parallelize a collection, all Datasources will provide Rows or Internal rows to Spark so your encoder will not be used for most sources.

Comment: DS's not mature enough yet.

Comment: May be add an example and comparison. Upvote already for that. helps all

Comment: @RussS thanks for the answer. you said “can ignore the differences between dataframe/dataset if you don’t use those functions”. but what are those differences in the case encoders are used. If i have a dataframe with a defined schema and an equivalent dataset, how are the encoders for the two different if at all. Is there any advantage in encoding having a strongly typed case class vs a generic Row?

Comment: I can't imagine there being a significant difference. Once you have hit a serialization boundary you are paying a huge price and leaving the internal row format (tungsten). That cost dwarfs any particularities of what object you encode into IMHO.

Comment: @thebluephantom an example of what, also the dataset API is quite mature. As I said before a Dataframe is a specific type of data set, it's actually a type alias of Dataset[Row]

Comment: Well I get the latter, but you state using the DF etc. I concur there. Anyway.